# llamado a una API solo con callbacks, trabajando en node con xmlhttp

Tags: javascript

estoy desarrollando un ejercicio, pedir datos a una API solo con callbacks, sin caer en la piramide de la muerte, la parte de la funcion fetchData la comprendo excepto los callbacks:

```
let XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
let url_api = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/';

function fetchData(url_api, callback) {    
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();       
xhttp.open('GET', url_api, true);      
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (event) {      
    if(xhttp.readyState === 4) {        
        if(xhttp.status === 200) {      
            callback(null, JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)); 
        } else {       
            const error = new Error('Error' + url_api) 
            return callback(error, null)        
        };
    };
};
xhttp.send();
```

Aqui viene el inconveniente mayor, aun no logro entender bien el anidamiento de los 3 llamados a la API y de donde nacen el error1, error2 y error 3 si no esta declarada en la funcion principal:

```
fetchData(url_api, (error1, data1) => {
 if(error1) return console.error(error1);
  fetchData(url_api + data1.results[0].id, (error2, data2) => {
   if(error2) return console.error(error2);
    fetchData(data2.origin.url, (error3, data3) => {
     if(error3) return console.error(error3);
```

espero la ayuda de la comunidad con respecto a los callbacks... saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La función principal ejecutará `callback()` siempre con dos parámetros, error y resultado, sin importar el nombre que tú les asignes en la función `callback()`.

> Aquí viene el inconveniente mayor, aun no logro entender bien el anidamiento de los 3 llamados a la API y de donde nacen el error1, error2 y error 3 si no esta declarada en la función principal

Eres tú quien define el nombre de esas variables al crear las funciones y no necesitan estar presentes en la función principal con ese mismo nombre.

Vamos a suponer que en lugar de funciones anónimas, creas las funciones aparte:

```
// Tú defines los nombres de los parámetros a recibir
function callback1(error1, data1) {
    if(error1) {
        // Mostrar error en consola y salir
        console.log(error1);
        return false;
    }
    // Hacer algo con data1, probablemente otra petición
}

// Ejecutar petición y agregar la función que se debe ejecutar
// sabiendo que fetchData la ejecutará enviándole dos parámetros
fetchData(url_api, callback1);
```

Usando [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) es exactamente lo mismo, entre paréntesis estás definiendo la cantidad de parámetros a recibir y sus respectivos nombres:

```
fetchData(url_api, (parametro1, parametro2) => {
    if(parametro1) {
        // Hubo error, mostrar en consola
        console.log(parametro1);
        return false;
    }
    // parametro2 contiene los datos devueltos por la API
    // Ejecutar siguiente petición
});
```

Comment: @Miltonext, no, depende de la API, en tu caso, siempre devuelve dos parámetros, pero puede haber otra que devuelva uno, más o, incluso, ninguno.

Comment: Entiendo entonces que el uso los callbacks para realizar peticiones a una API siempre van a recibir si o si dos parámetros que uno es el error y otro el resultado. Usando callbacks en funciones que no trabajan con APIs esos dos parámetros no son necesarios, sino el callback y los parámetros o parámetro ya sea cual fuera van de acuerdo a la lógica de la función que quisiera crear... Es esto correcto?

Comment: De hecho, lo que devuelve 2 parámetros es la función `fetchData()`, la API parece devolver siempre un texto que se debe interpretar, el error se genera en la función por el tipo de encabezado recibido.

Comment: @Miltonext, tú eres quien decide cuántas variables se van a crear en la función, de acuerdo a la respuesta de la API y debes crear las funciones callback para recibir esas variables como parámetro.